# How to bind return function to markup angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-bind

```
<li ng-click="toggleTables('all')" class="active">
    <span>All Tags (getTotal('allTerms'))
        <span ng-bind="getTotal('allTerms')"></span>
    </span>
</li>
```

I'm trying to get the returned value from the function `getTotal` to show up in the markup, however the value is not showing up, the function is below:

```
function getTotal(key) {
    console.log('getTotal',key);
    return totals[key].totals; // 33
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a controller?, if that is the case why don't you use a variable instead like this

```
$scope.total = 0;
function getTotal(key) {
    $scope.total = totals[key].totals; 
}

<span ng-bind="total"></span>
```

Comment: Ah thanks! Yeah I had something like this before, but was trying to avoid $$watches. Will have to revert, 7 more minutes!

Answer (score 1):

You also can bind function. Check sample - https://jsfiddle.net/dkjk6bng/

```
<span ng-bind="getTotal('allTerms')"></span>

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.totals = {
    'allTerms': {
      totals: 33
    }
  };
  $scope.getTotal = function(key) {
    console.log('getTotal', key);
    return $scope.totals[key].totals; // 33
  }
});
```

Hope this will help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<span>{{getTotal('allTerms')}}</span>
```